# Jetpack Compose: How to align sub-buttons above the floating action button centrally?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have an Expandable/Collapsible floating action button menu. That menu has sub-buttons with labels as the following:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
enum class ButtonState {
    COLLAPSED,
    EXPANDED
}


@Composable
fun MenuButton(
    iconRotationDegree: Float,
    onButtonClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    buttonSize: Dp = 32.dp
) {
    Button(
        onClick = {
            onButtonClick()
        },
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            backgroundColor = colorResource(
                color.primary_color,
            ),
            contentColor = colorResource(color.on_primary)
        ),
        modifier = modifier
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .size(buttonSize),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
    ) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_add),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .rotate(iconRotationDegree)
                .size(buttonSize / 2f)

        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun MenuItem(
    size: Dp,
    label: String,
    @DrawableRes icon: Int,
    onMenuItemClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    labelModifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    parentModifier:Modifier = Modifier,
) {

    Row(
        modifier = parentModifier,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ) {
        MenuItemLabel(label = label, modifier = labelModifier)
        Button(
            onClick = {
                onMenuItemClick()
            },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                backgroundColor = colorResource(
                    R.color.primary_color,
                ),
                contentColor = colorResource(R.color.on_primary)
            ),
            modifier = modifier
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .size(size),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
        ) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = icon),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(size / 1.8f)
            )
        }
    }
}
   val buttonSize = 48.dp

    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End) {

        arrange.forEach { index ->
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = buttonState) {
                val delayDuration = if (buttonState == ButtonState.EXPANDED) 200L else 75L
                delay(delayDuration * index)
                animatableList[index].animateTo(
                    if (buttonState == ButtonState.EXPANDED) 1f else 0f,
                    animationSpec = keyframes {
                        durationMillis = 200
                        if (buttonState == ButtonState.EXPANDED) {
                            0.0f at 0 with LinearEasing
                            0.2f at 15 with LinearEasing
                            0.4f at 75 with LinearEasing
                            0.6f at 100 with LinearEasing
                            1.0f at 120 with LinearEasing
                            1.5f at 150 with EaseOutBounce
                            1.2f at 170 with FastOutLinearInEasing
                            1.1f at 180 with FastOutLinearInEasing
                            1.0f at 200 with FastOutLinearInEasing
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
            MenuItem(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .scale(1f)
                    .alpha(1f),
                labelModifier = Modifier.alpha(1f),
                size = buttonSize / 2,
                icon = drawable.ic_add,
                label = "Label $index",
                onMenuItemClick = { /*TODO*/ })


        }

        MenuButton(
            buttonSize = buttonSize,
            iconRotationDegree = iconRotationDegree,
            onButtonClick = {
                buttonState =
                    if (buttonState == ButtonState.EXPANDED) ButtonState.COLLAPSED else ButtonState.EXPANDED
            })
    }
```

The problem is, I want the sub-buttons to be centrally aligned above the `MenuButton` as the following:

[image]

However, as you can see, they are aligned at the end because: `Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End)`. If I set the alignment to center it just centers `MenuButton`. I guess the `Column` composable is not fit in this case but I don't know what should I use or how to implement it.

Comment: https://medium.com/@dawinderapps/floatingactionbutton-with-sub-floating-items-in-jetpack-compose-734fac0c9116

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add padding based on FAB `size` passed to the `MenuItem`. In the `MenuItem` change `modifier` of the `Button` to

```
modifier = modifier
    .padding(size / 2)
    .size(size)
    .clip(CircleShape),
```